# primeng issues with rc5

Tags: angular, primeng, angular2-upgrade

After upgrading to rc5, and reinstalling primeng with the new release, I receive the following error:

zone.js?1472019041780:484 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'icon' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. ("ver':hovered,'ui-state-focus':focused,'ui-state-disabled':disabled}" >][icon]="icon" pButton *ngIf="showIcon" (click)="onButtonClick($event,in)" [ngClass]="): **Calendar@7:31** ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:

I tried removing all references to calendar, so I can at least get the app up and running, and got another issue:

```
Can't bind to 'rows' since it isn't a known property of 'p-paginator'.
1. If 'p-paginator' is an Angular component and it has 'rows' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-paginator' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("              <ng-content select="header"></ng-content>
            </div>
            <p-paginator [ERROR ->][rows]="rows" [first]="first" [totalRecords]="totalRecords" [pageLinkSize]="pageLinks" styleClass="ui"): DataTable@6:25
Can't bind to 'first' since it isn't a known property of 'p-paginator'.
1. If 'p-paginator' is an Angular component and it has 'first' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-paginator' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("<ng-content select="header"></ng-content>
            </div>
```

dependancies:

```
import { NgModule, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Calendar, DataTable, Column, InputMask } from 'primeng/primeng';
```

Comment: reordered and edited minification, as sugested here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618, and now get the same error on another object: `zone.js?1472029134433:484 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'showItBootstrap' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("k]="['/about']">ABOUT</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i hinted to in the comments above, there is a issue with RC5 which produces this error. In most cases, it is enough to disable minimization, or adjust the settings to the build, and configure uglify with mangle:

```
{ screw_ie8 : true, keep_fnames: true} or use AOT template compilation
```

The source to this issue and the solution is [github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618](http://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618)
this fix didn't work for me though, but i hope it will help other developers.

Answer (score 6):

You need to import everything as an xModule. See [Primafaces' blog](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=4059) for reference.

The new method is the following:

```
import {NgModule}      from '@angular/core';
import {InputTextModule,DataTableModule,ButtonModule,DialogModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
 
@NgModule({
  imports:      [BrowserModule,InputTextModule,DataTableModule,ButtonModule,DialogModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
  providers:    [CarService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Edit: Let me correct myself. I use submodules and only one of the submodule relies on PrimeNg so I thought it would be enough to import the dependecies there. It turns out that I have to import these modules in my app.module.ts (my main module) and not in my submodule. Sadly, I don't know the exact reason why.

PS.: I don't know why do you get 'unexpected value'. Can you maybe share more information about your project?

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case the link is no longer available.

Comment: thanks. got Unexpected value 'xModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'(…)

Comment: apparently this is a known error, and i get it for several 3ed part packages. but non of the suggested 'workarounds' helped. see github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618

Comment: Maybe [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#what-does-_can-t-bind-to-x-since-it-isn-t-a-known-property-of-y-_-mean-) will be helpful for others.

>>What does "Can't bind to 'x' since it isn't a known property of 'y'" mean?
This error usually means either that you neglected to declare the directive "x" or you haven't imported the module to which "x" belongs.<<

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that not only you need to import everything, but also
 in system.config.js you need to add  `@angular/forms` in `packageNames`.  Also in your boot or main need to change to the following:

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

I got prime DataTable working with RC5 and primeng 1.0.0-beta.14